# HTML 5 Input Pattern

Tags: html

I am attempting to restrict an input to A-Z and a-z with a minimum of 1 character and a maximum of 20 and it doesn't seem to be working.

```html
<form>
  <input name=Last_Name type=text pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" placeholder=Smith>
</form>
```

Everytime I attempt to submit with a proper input it error with "Please match the requested format".

Comment: I edited your code to be a live demo and include a form so the patter could be triggered. I couldn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know there was code snippets. Been awhile lol.

Comment: You need to read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). With that pattern Miles O'Brian, Edward Tudor-Pole and everyone from one of the 张/張 families is going to find it rather hard to use your form.

Comment: Quentin thanks but this is a predictable pattern as it is an internal website.

Comment: I'm now really curious about what sort of entity has an internal website with such predictable names.

Comment: Middle of nowhere in the midwest of the US.

Comment: That's no guarantee of never hiring someone with an apostrophe in their name!

Comment: Correct, we would just remove it. Most of our systems won't accept none A-Za-z characters for names. So we default to that when programming in something that could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work properly, except that the minimum length will be ignored because the pattern match only starts to be used if there is a value entered.

If you leave the textfield blank, it will not run the pattern to validate, so even though it wouldn't match your pattern, it will be valid.

So in addition to that, add a `required` attribute. This works for me:

```html
<form>
    <input name=Last_Name type=text pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,20}" required placeholder=Smith />
    <button type="submit">Test</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is odd is your code snippet works, but when its "live" it doesn't. The actual line is `echo "<td style=\"text-align:left\"><input name=First_Name type=text pattern=\"[A-Za-z]{20}\" placeholder=John required></td>";` as its in PHP

Comment: Verify that the generated HTML code is the same, if it isn't, copy the entire form, exclude all other fields and verify if that's similar to the HTML code in my answer.

Comment: The generated code is what I pasted from my example. I pulled it from the source after loading the site.

Comment: it is valid as well, however, by removing the 1 from `{1,20}` you changed your pattern, it is only valid now if it is **exactly** 20 characters, keep that in mind.

Comment: There we go I have 2 lines right on top of each other missed I removed the 1. Thanks.